# Vimeo to record videos using a camcorder

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

Can I use Vimeo in my web application  to record a video from my laptop which is connected to a camcorder ?  Camcorder exposes JAVA API's which supports START / STOP / Zoom-in  and all other camera options.

Answer (score 0):

Vimeo was not created to record a video. It's just a video hosting platform similar to youtube but for professionals.

You need to be doing the recording and then use either their interface or their API to upload a video.

In your case, you could imagine creating an intermediate application that connects to your Camcorder's exposed API, gets the recorded video, and uploads it using Vimeo's API.

[Here](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/libraries) is an official list of libraries and sdk's that Vimeo proposes to simplify the API usage.